# Mean of Posterior Predictive Distribution with dice and coin

Tags: self-study, bayesian

In this exercise, $X$ equals $1$ if we get heads in a coin flip, and $0$ otherwise.

$X\sim \mathrm{Binomial}\left(1,\theta\right)$

I've already found the posterior distribution of $\theta$:

$\theta\:\mid\:\underset{\sim}{x} \:\sim\mathrm{Beta}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i,\:n-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\right);\:E\left[\theta\mid\underset{\sim}{x}\right]=\bar{x}$

Now we are interested in predicting a random variable $Y$, which represents the number of heads obtained following the process: we throw a dice and register the number of obtained points $(r)$. Then, we throw the coin $r$ times; the objective of the exercise is to find the **mean** of the posterior predictive distribution of $Y$.

I've created the random variable $R$, which represents the number of points we get throwing the dice: $E[R] = 3.5$. Also, $Y \sim\mathrm{Binomial}\left(R,\theta\right) $.

My problem is with the notation. I want to say that the expected value of $Y$ is $3.5\:\theta$, but I don't know if it's represented $E[Y\mid\theta]$ or $E[Y\mid\theta,r]$. That has consequences in the mean of the posterior predictive distribution of $Y$: Is it:

$E\left[Y\mid\underset{\sim}{x}\right] = E\left[E[Y\mid\underset{\sim}{x},\theta]\mid\underset{\sim}{x}\right] = E\left[E[Y\mid\theta]\mid\underset{\sim}{x}\right] = 3.5\: E\left[\theta\mid\underset{\sim}{x}\right] = 3.5\:\bar{x}$

Or

$E\left[Y\mid\underset{\sim}{x}\right] = E\left[E[Y\mid\underset{\sim}{x},\theta]\mid\underset{\sim}{x}\right] = E\left[E\left[E[Y\mid\underset{\sim}{x},\theta,r]\mid\underset{\sim}{x},\theta\right]\mid\underset{\sim}{x}\right]= 3.5\: E\left[\theta\mid\underset{\sim}{x}\right] = 3.5\:\bar{x}$

Thanks in advance.